# Laravel 5 FormRequest custom message for array input

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-5

I have a form input with an `email`-field, `email_confirmation`-field and then `fname`- & `lname`-fields that can be cloned using javascript so multiple names can be added.

The input variables are consequently named `email`, `email_confirmation` and `persons[0][fname]` + `persons[0][lname]` respectively (with incrementing index 0 if multiple names were supplied).

I'm trying to set custom validation messages for an array input:

in `RegisterRequest.php`

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = array();
    foreach ($this->input('persons') as $index => $person) {
        $fname = 'persons.' . $index . '.fname';
        $lname = 'persons.' . $index . '.lname';
        $rules[$fname] = 'sometimes|required_with:'.$lname.'|max:25';
        $rules[$lname] = 'sometimes|required_with:'.$fname.'|max:35';
    }
    return array_merge([
        'email' => 'required|confirmed|email',
        'email_confirmation' => 'required',
    ], $rules);
}

public function messages()
{
    $array = array(
        'email.required' => 'Je e-mailadres is verplicht.',
        'email.email' => 'Dit is geen geldig e-mailadres',
        'email.confirmed' => 'E-mailadressen komen niet overeen.',
        'email_confirmation.required' => 'Bevestig je e-mailadres.',
    );
    foreach ($this->input('persons') as $index => $person) {
        $fname = 'persons.' . $index . '.fname';
        $lname = 'persons.' . $index . '.lname';
        $array[$fname.'.max:25'] = 'Je kan maximaal 25 karakters ingeven.';
        $array[$lname.'.max:35'] = 'Je kan maximaal 35 karakters ingeven.';
        $array[$fname.'.required_with:' . $lname] = 'Vul de voornaam in.';
        $array[$lname.'.required_with:' .$fname] = 'Vul de achternaam in.';
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Email error message is correctly being displayed, but unfortunately the messages for the input array don't... Any ideas how to achieve this? I think the problem lies in the fact that validation messages are defined using the dot rule (`attribute.rule`), but my input array attribute also consists of dots...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the custom messages you don't specify the actual validation rule with parameters. Just it's name:

```
$array[$fname.'.max'] = 'Je kan maximaal 25 karakters ingeven.';
$array[$lname.'.max'] = 'Je kan maximaal 35 karakters ingeven.';
$array[$fname.'.required_with'] = 'Vul de voornaam in.';
$array[$lname.'.required_with'] = 'Vul de achternaam in.';
```

For the `max` validation you may use the `:max` placeholder inside your message to retrieve the number that's passed to the rule:

```
$array[$fname.'.max'] = 'Je kan maximaal :max karakters ingeven.';
$array[$lname.'.max'] = 'Je kan maximaal :max karakters ingeven.';
```

Comment: Didn't know it would be *this* simple.. :) I clearly overlooked the parameters! Thanks for the quick reply!